# Showing an autohidden panel only when the mouse is in a corner

Tags: panel, xfce, xubuntu

I recently installed xubuntu and I'm trying to get one of my panel that I have on autohide to only show when my mouse is in the bottom left corner instead of whenever my mouse is on the left side. Is this possible to do?

Comment: I have not tried it, but I keep reading that a program called brightside will do the trick. If that doesn't work or you have trouble, check out this forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218063